# System.InvalidProgramException Invalid IL code in System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext:.ctor (string,string): method body is empty

Tags: entity-framework, mono, raspberry-pi

Im using mono(3.0.3) on a raspberry pi. Everything is working properly except entity framework. I can login with no problem into my site but the second I enter an area where there is entity framework i get the following error with XSP:

```
Application Exception
System.InvalidProgramException
Invalid IL code in System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext:.ctor (string,string): method body is empty.

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): AdwenModel.
Exception stack trace:
  at AdwenModel.AdwenEntities1..ctor (System.String connectionString) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at AdwenWeb.App_Code.AdwenConnection.getDataContextAdwen () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at AdwenWeb.Management.overview.createObjectTable () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at AdwenWeb.Management.overview.Page_Load (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad (System.EventArgs e) [0x00029] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.UI/Control.cs:1211 
  at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive () [0x00031] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.UI/Control.cs:1641 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessLoad () [0x0004a] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.UI/Page.cs:1490 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData () [0x0004d] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.UI/Page.cs:1475 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.InternalProcessRequest () [0x001bf] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.UI/Page.cs:1442 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00062] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.UI/Page.cs:1269 
Version Information: 3.0.3 (master/c1b505c Thu Dec 6 09:17:47 UTC 2012); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020
```

Don't really know what else could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about the Entity Framework support in Mono but what I do know is that they have included EF6 in Mono, and System.Data.Objects is no longer the namespace for ObjectContext in EF6. Whatever is causing the failure should be looking for System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes you are right! What Mono team only says is: As of Mono 2.11.3, Microsoft's open sourced EntityFramework is part of Mono's distribution. link: http://www.mono-project.com/EntityFramework

They do no specify anything else! I have to go into the dungeons of the world wide web to find out. The could have elaborate a bit more on this page.

Comment: Did you find out the code that incorrectly refers to the System.Data.Objects namespace? My only guess looking at the exception is that the existing open source code form MVC and EF6 has been included into Mono verbatim, and the fact that the MVC codebase depends on EF5 (which isn't open source and isn't included in Mono) hasn't been accounted for.

Comment: If the code that refers to the System.Data.Objects namespace is part of your project, you can simply edit the namespaces to reflect the new locations in EF6, e.g. DbContext and Code First APIs are still in the same namespaces as before, under System.Data.Entity, but most of the other APIs that were originally included in .NET have moved under System.Data.Entity.Core.

Comment: I tried a couple of things today like upgrading to Visual Studio 2012 and .NET framework 4.5. But that did not go well. My whole solution is not compatible with VS2012.  And in VS2010 I cannot target the .NET 4.5. I thought targeting 4.5 would be a better solutions for going to the right assemblies. But I'm pretty much stuck at the moment.

Comment: Actually EF6 includes builds for both .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5. The main difference between the two is that the .NET 4.5 version includes s new async API and the definition of DataAnnotations that are missing in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll .NET 4.0. I don't know if Mono require using Visual Studio 2012, but I know EF6 does not.

Comment: yes I found this link http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Updating%20Applications%20to%20use%20EF6
and I realise that I'm not far away from home but I takes some more to get this working. E.G. I removed all the system.data.enty.dll references from my projects. My datamodel project is not taking that well. I got 480 errors when I remove System.Data.Entity.dll from this project. It does not pickup entityframework.dll. Also I read I need to (re)build a provider for my sqlite db. So It will take some time again to understand and get everything correct...